# PayPal gateway has rejected request for Magento order

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I create a Magento order in backgroup. But when I click 'submit order' it displays an error:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token).

I chose payment method "paypal express checkout".

How could this be solved?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise. I also fixed grammar and formatted the error with blockquote - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I would advise you to edit the question and provide more information and possibly code about the specific error-message you're encountering. Good luck!

Comment: Reach out to https://www.paypal-techsupport.com on this one, provide them the correlation id from the API response if you have it.